# Unable to restart MySQL on CentOS 7 after resetting root user password

Tags: mysql, centos, lamp

I have reset the MySQL root user password using the following steps

1. Stop MySQL

`# systemctl stop mysqld`

2. Start safe mode

`# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

3. Logged in as root

`# mysql -u root`

4. Reset Password

`use mysql;`

`update user set password=PASSWORD("newpassword") WHERE user='root';`

`flush privileges;`

`quit;`

5. Stop MySQL safe mode

`# systemctl stop mysqld`

6. Start MySQL

`# systemctl start mysqld`

## I am getting the following message when trying to restart

`# systemctl restart mysqld`

```
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[root@li1456-180 ~]# systemctl status mysqld.service

● mysqld.service - MySQL Community Server

   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)

   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2016-04-26 07:23:19 UTC; 10s ago

  Process: 13293 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

  Process: 13292 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

  Process: 13280 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 Main PID: 13292 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 26 07:23:18 li1456-180.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Apr 26 07:23:18 li1456-180.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.

Apr 26 07:23:18 li1456-180.members.linode.com systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.

Apr 26 07:23:19 li1456-180.members.linode.com systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.

Apr 26 07:23:19 li1456-180.members.linode.com systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service

Apr 26 07:23:19 li1456-180.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Apr 26 07:23:19 li1456-180.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.

Apr 26 07:23:19 li1456-180.members.linode.com systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure the answer is on `/var/log/messages`.

On another terminal:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep -i mysql
```

restart mysql

```
systemctl restart mysqld
```

check the log and find the error, if still cannot solve it, please post it so we can help you more.

Comment: I'm getting mysqld_safe: 160426 09:02:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.

mysqld_safe: 160426 09:02:47 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

Comment: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Comment: Do the same with /var/log/mysqld.log

Comment: Seems like it's not restarting as it should, do `stop` and then `start` while checking the log, it may appear another error.

Comment: same error mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists. tried stop then start

Comment: kill the process then. Get the `PID` using `ps auxww | grep mysql` and kill them `kill <PID>` or just use `killall mysql`